# What is the “Persistence Bit” iwlwifi

Tags: wifi, firmware, iwlwifi

When booting I am receiving the following error from iwlwifi:

> iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: Error, can not clear persistence bit

In addition to the error it seems the interface is not being renamed (it remains `wlan0` instead of `wlp58s0`) and is additionally not recognized as a station by iwd.

This only started happening recently but downgrading `linux-firmware` which contains iwlwifi did not resolve the issue.

What is this persistence bit and how can I clear it to resolve the issue?

Comment: https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-wireless/msg179652.html (but I have no idea what to do or even if it's related to your issue)

Comment: @A.B That definitely looks like where the error is being reported from. I imagine that patch made it in a while ago though so strange that the issue has only cropped up now.